# Lists inside big numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I want to use some parts of a big Numpy array. However, Python nagged because this smaller part of the array wasn't actually a Numpy array, but a list. So I looked into it and found out that Numpy actually stored multiple list within the big Numpy array. This only happens when a Numpy array has a certain size. So, my questions are:

- Why is numpy doing that?
- Is there a way to prevent this and thus only have a big Numpy array?
- What's the threshold size, after Numpy start doing this?

Here are two different Numpy arrays to clarify my question. The first one is a standard Numpy array and the second one adopts the behavior with multiple lists inside explained above.

```
bigger_array = np.array([
    [[[0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.05, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
      [0.05, 0.05, 0.5, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.05, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0],
      [0.0, 0.0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.5, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05],
      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.5, 0.05], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.5]],
     [[0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.05, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
      [0.05, 0.05, 0.5, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.05, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0],
      [0.0, 0.0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.5, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05],
      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.5, 0.05], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.5]]],

    [[[0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125]],
     [[0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125]]],

    [[[0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125]],
     [[0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125],
      [0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125]]]
])


smaller-array = np.array([
    [[[0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05], [0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05],
      [0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05], [0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05]],

     [[0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05], [0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05],
      [0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05], [0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05]]],

    [[[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05],
      [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05]],
     [[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05],
      [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05]]],

    [[[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05],
      [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05]],
     [[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05],
      [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05]]]
])

print(type(bigger_array[0][0]))
print(type(smaller_array[0][0]))
```

Comment: It's not a matter of overall size.  It's the size of the lists that matters.  If they differ, you'll the array of lists, as opposed to a multidimensional array.  Check the `dtype`.  It will be `object` in the brokenup case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subelements of the list forming `bigger_array` are of different sizes. If you fix that, then numpy will return an array.

```
print([len(x) for y in bigger_array for x in y])  # [8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

If you need to store sequences of different sizes in a numpy array, you can create an empty array of maximal size and then fill it:

```
big_array = np.empty(2, 4)
big_array[0] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
big_array[1, :-1] = [1, 2, 3]
```

You will just need to keep in mind which elements have not been set.

One way of doing this is keeping a boolean mask array that tells you whether an element has been set or not.

```
mask = np.ones_like(big_array, dtype=bool)
mask[-1, -1] = False
mask
```

returns

```
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False]])
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like I misssed that! Would have been weird if they go for lists in big numpy arrays..