# Removing zero values from a numpy array of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Original datas

```
 [[ 0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00 -6.76207728e+00 -1.63236398e+01]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  2.51283367e+01  1.13952157e+02]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  3.11402956e+00 -5.16009612e+02]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  3.10969787e+01  1.82175649e+02]
 [ 1.00000000e+00 -2.31269114e+00 -4.13720127e+02  3.55395844e+03]
 [ 1.00000000e+00  4.54598490e+01  6.19694322e+02  2.61091335e+03]
 [ 1.00000000e+00  7.36925014e-01 -4.49386738e+02 -1.22392549e+03]
 [ 1.00000000e+00  3.29511609e+00 -4.43413555e+02 -4.12677155e+03]]
```

I tried to remove zeros with this ode below

```
def removeZeroPadding(X):
  res = []
  for poly in enumerate(X):
      tmp = poly[1]
      tmp = tmp[tmp != 0]
      res.append(tmp)
  return res
```

This transforms into

```
[array([  1.        ,  -6.76207728, -16.32363975]), array([  1.        ,  25.1283367 , 113.95215706]), array([   1.        ,    3.11402956, -516.0096117 ]), array([  1.        ,  31.09697873, 182.17564943]), array([ 1.00000000e+00, -2.31269114e+00, -4.13720127e+02,  3.55395844e+03]), array([1.00000000e+00, 4.54598490e+01, 6.19694322e+02, 2.61091335e+03]), array([ 1.00000000e+00,  7.36925014e-01, -4.49386738e+02, -1.22392549e+03]), array([ 1.00000000e+00,  3.29511609e+00, -4.43413555e+02, -4.12677155e+03])]
```

How can I keep the structures of the original data with no zeros? Thanks

edit: it should look like this

```
 [[ 1.00000000e+00 -6.76207728e+00 -1.63236398e+01]
 [ 1.00000000e+00  2.51283367e+01  1.13952157e+02]
 [ 1.00000000e+00  3.11402956e+00 -5.16009612e+02]
 [ 1.00000000e+00  3.10969787e+01  1.82175649e+02]
 [ 1.00000000e+00 -2.31269114e+00 -4.13720127e+02  3.55395844e+03]
 [ 1.00000000e+00  4.54598490e+01  6.19694322e+02  2.61091335e+03]
 [ 1.00000000e+00  7.36925014e-01 -4.49386738e+02 -1.22392549e+03]
 [ 1.00000000e+00  3.29511609e+00 -4.43413555e+02 -4.12677155e+03]]
```

Comment: Numpy provides a trim method

Comment: what do you want instead of the zeros?

Comment: try this, ``arr[arr != 0]``

Comment: Do you want to look for columns consisting of all 0's and remove those?

Comment: @warped It sohuld just remove zeros [0 1 2 3] to be [1 2 3]

Comment: With “keep the structures”, you mean you want to keep the initial dimensions of your array (i.e. 4 by 6 in your example)? If so, what values should take the place of your zeros? None?

Comment: @shmulvad yes exackly

Comment: if you remove the zeros and replace htem with nothing, the structure will change.

Comment: @warped sorry for misunderstanding. what I meant was, in the output there should be no "array([1. , 3434, 3. 4545])" etc.

Comment: @Thunfische You can’t. It’s not possible to have a matrix where some rows have only 3 elements and some have 4. That’s not possible. That’s why you end up with an array of array with different sizes.

Comment: You won't keep the same structure then. Try doing `np.array([[1,2,3], [4]])`. You'll see that you end up with `array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4])], dtype=object)` of shape `(2,)` whereas `np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])` yields `array([[1, 2], [1, 2]])` with shape `(2,2)`.

Comment: Explain how a list of 3 and 4 length arrays is supposed to have the same 'structure' as a (8,4) array of floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you do not want a list of arrays as the output but instead want a 2-dimensional array (i.e. `[[...]]` instead of `[array([...]), array([...])]`).

However, this is not possible as the rows of your array end up with different sizes after you trim them by removing the zeros (*i.e. some end up having 3 elements and some have 4*). If you want it to be a single array, same as for matrices in mathematics, all columns (*and all rows*) will need to have the same number of elements.

As an alternative, you could assign the elements you want to trim a different value, e.g. `None`, or you can [create an empty array and fill it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49179023/8725354).

Answer (score 1):

What you seek is fundamentally impossible. You can't both remove a variable number of entries from each row and at the same time be guaranted that each row has the same number of entries (which is required to get a `ndarray` of type `[[...]]`. [hlzl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62373817/9248793) explains this in more detail.

This following function will remove `0`-entries from the left and right side of each row, but what it returns will be of type `[array([...]), array([...])]`:

```py
def trim_zeros_in_rows(ndarr):
    return np.array([np.trim_zeros(row) for row in ndarr])

print(trim_zeros_in_rows(np.array([[0., 0., 1., 0.],
                                   [2., 3., 4., 0.]])))
```

Prints:

```py
[array([1.]) array([2., 3., 4.])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trim_zeros.html[trim_zeros](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trim_zeros.html).

It will avoid the for loop